# Test Google Signin locally thought localhost

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, google-signin

yesterday I was testing an application to learn ReactJs and Redux and I got stuck testing it because the google signin was throwing and error:
"google-login.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'signIn' of null".

The problem is that I need to create a auth credential at https://console.developers.google.com and add whitelist http://localhost:3000.

The thing is that I cannot create a credential to my localhost to Authorized domains.

I have been searching about the topic and I did not get with a clear solution.

Surely it is not something difficult for some of you. I hope you can help me with this.

Comment: I was able to whitelist localhost:3000 when clicking on credentials in https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials What is exactly that you can't do?